# How to use lifecycle methods with hooks in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have gone through hooks introduced in react v16.7.0.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

So my understanding about hooks is we can play with state in functional component without writing class components in react. This is really amazing feature.

But I am not getting clear picture about using hooks in functional components.

```
   import { useState } from 'react';

   function Example() {
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
         Click me
        </button>
      </div>
   );
  }
```

how can I use life cycle methods in the above functional component if I use hooks?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns

Comment: useState() by itself is not a lifecycle method. it just creates a running state. lifecycle methods are conditinally called ,unlike your call to useState. great topic though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks and Component Lifecycle Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254017/react-hooks-and-component-lifecycle-equivalent)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here are examples for the most common lifecycles:

### `componentDidMount`

Pass an empty array as the second argument to `useEffect()` to run only the callback on mount only.

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, []); // Pass an empty array to run only callback on mount only.

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### `componentDidUpdate` (loose)

By passing just the single argument into `useEffect`, it will run after every render. This is a loose equivalent because there's a slight difference here being `componentDidUpdate` will not run after the first render but this hooks version runs after every render.

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }); // No second argument, so run after every render.

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### `componentDidUpdate` (strict)

The difference of this example with the example above is that the callback here would not run on initial render, strictly emulating the semantics of `componentDidUpdate`. This [answer is by Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254028/1751946), all credit goes to him.

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const firstUpdate = useRef(true);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (firstUpdate.current) {
      firstUpdate.current = false;
      return;
    }

    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>componentDidUpdate: {count} times</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### `componentWillUnmount`

Return a callback in `useEffect`'s callback argument and it will be called before unmounting.

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Return a callback in useEffect and it will be called before unmounting.
    return () => {
      console.log('componentWillUnmount!');
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### `shouldComponentUpdate`

You can already achieve this on the component level using `React.PureComponent` or `React.memo`. For preventing rerendering of the child components, this example is taken from [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate):

```
function Parent({ a, b }) {
  // Only re-rendered if `a` changes:
  const child1 = useMemo(() => <Child1 a={a} />, [a]);
  // Only re-rendered if `b` changes:
  const child2 = useMemo(() => <Child2 b={b} />, [b]);
  return (
    <>
      {child1}
      {child2}
    </>
  )
}
```

### `getDerivedStateFromProps`

Again, taken from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops)

```
function ScrollView({row}) {
  let [isScrollingDown, setIsScrollingDown] = useState(false);
  let [prevRow, setPrevRow] = useState(null);

  if (row !== prevRow) {
    // Row changed since last render. Update isScrollingDown.
    setIsScrollingDown(prevRow !== null && row > prevRow);
    setPrevRow(row);
  }

  return `Scrolling down: ${isScrollingDown}`;
}
```

### `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`

No equivalent for hooks yet.

### `componentDidCatch`

No equivalent for hooks yet.

Comment: That’s clean and perfect answer. Thanks you:)

Comment: what is componentWillMount?

Comment: The `useEffect` callback  in the `componentWillUnmount ` example will be called each time before re-rendering, and not only when unmounting the component. The correct implementation would use `useRef` and a `[]` deps array, e.g.: `const onUnmountRef = useRef(() => console.log("componentWillUnmount!"));
  useEffect(() => onUnmountRef.current, []);`

Comment: Good catch. Updated

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` is a close alternative to `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`. Using `useRef` you can only make it fire on update and not on mount.

Comment: const isMountedRef = useRef(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (isMountedRef.current) {
    }
  }

Answer (score 2):

Well, you don't really have lifecycle methods. =) But you could use the effect hook as shown here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

The effect hook will be able to replicate the behavior of componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount

So you really don't need lifecycle methods in the component. The effect hook is taking their place instead. =)

Read the link above and you will get a few examples on how they work.

Comment: Ok. But what if I want to use static getDerivedStateFromProps and shouldComponentUpdate methods in hooks?

Answer (score 2):

The React team has provided a `useEffect` hook for this purpose. Let's take the component in your example and add server uploading for the count, which we would otherwise put in e.g. `componentDidUpdate`:

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

 function Example() {
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   useEffect(() => {
     fetch(
       'server/url',
       {
         headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({count}),
       }
     ); 
   });

   return (
     <div>
       <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
       <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
         Click me
       </button>
     </div>
   );
 }
```

This doesn't seem like a huge win in this example because it isn't. But the problem with the lifecycle methods is that you only get one of each of them in your component. What if you want to upload to the server, and trigger an event, and put a message on a queue, and none of those things are related? Too bad, they all get crammed together in `componentDidUpdate`. Or you have `n` layers of wrapped HOCs for your `n` things you want to do. But with hooks, you can split all of those up into decoupled calls to `useEffect` without unnecessary layers of HOCs.

Comment: CAn useEffect be used multiple times? Also how about static getDerivedStateFromProps and shouldComponentUpdate in hooks?

Comment: @Think-Twice yup, you can use as many calls to `useEffect` in the definition of your component as you need. For `shouldComponentUpdate` the function has an optional second parameter which is a list of the values to watch e.g. `useEffect(uploadToTheServer, [count])`. I don't know about `getDerivedStateFromProps` because that runs *before* render. You *may* still need to use a class for that IDK, this is all pretty new to me too.

Answer (score 1):

Functional components are purly stateless components. But in React 16.8, they have added Hooks. Hooks can be used in place of state and lifecycle methods.

Yes, you can think of **useEffect** Hook as Like

- **componentDidMount**
- **componentDidUpdate**,
- **componentWillUnmount**
- **shouldComponentUpdate** combined.
- **Note** It is a close replacement for **componentDidMount** , **componentDidUpdate** and , **componentWillUnmount & shouldComponentUpdate**