# Re-render a child component (React with Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component called "Causes", and a child component called "Graph",

There's a hook called "datas", that is created and updated in "Causes" (parent), and I pass it as props to "Graph" (child).

The first time, everything works, but when I update "datas" in "Causes" (parent), "Graph" (child) still has the old "datas" array of objects.

How can I force the re-render of the child component ?

```
const [datas, setDatas] = useState([
    { shop: "00h-8h", value: 250, color: "#A2AAC2" },
    { shop: "8h-12h", value: 420, color: "#A2AAC2" },
    { shop: "12h-16h", value: 500, color: "#A2AAC2" },
    { shop: "16h-20h", value: 80, color: "#A2AAC2" },
    { shop: "20h-00h", value: 80, color: "#A2AAC2" }
]);

useEffect(() => {
  setDatas(newArray); <- this updates data, but the component below always got the old datas
}, []);


return (
  <Graph
                  h={400}
                  w={900}
                  data={datas}
                  defaultKeys={["shop", "value"]}
  />
)
```

Code available here : https://pastebin.com/aLzsz8md

Comment: I think this might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843675/componentwillreceiveprops-componentdidupdate-for-react-hook

Comment: need to see how you are creating `newArray` it needs to be a new reference

Comment: code here https://pastebin.com/aLzsz8md

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this problem by adding a key to the Graph component.

```
<Graph ... key={newKey} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to force a render of your component, you just need to call `setDatas()` with some new data.  Once you do that, it will rerender `Graph` with the new data.  Make sure you are calling `setDatas()` with a **new array**, not just an updated version of the existing `datas` array, it needs to be a new object reference

At the minute, you are only calling it once, on mount, using the `useEffect` hook (with no dependencies, denoted by the empty dependency array)

Comment: thats what I did, and with some console log I clearly see that datas value changes, but not the child component

Comment: can you post up the relevent code, from what you have posted, thats not clear

Comment: that's what's weird, i'm doing a few setDatas(newDatas), but the child component always get the datas in the first useState... no possibility to refresh it

Comment: have you got SimpleBarChart to see?

Comment: my hunch is something in your `shouldComponentUpdate` is not correct.  It may be worth debugging in there a little - it's the only thing I can see, though would stop your chart from rerendering, provided in your useEffect logging that you are seeing different data each time, and not the same values

Comment: the shouldcomponentupdate returns true if the props.data changes, and false if not, so it looks ok but i'll look further yes

Answer (score 0):

you missed the **return value** on the hook. Please see this implementation.

**Hook** (updateGraph.js)

```
const UpdateGraph = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        setData([
            { shop: "00h-8h", value: 250, color: "#A2AAC2" },
            { shop: "8h-12h", value: 420, color: "#A2AAC2" },
            { shop: "12h-16h", value: 500, color: "#A2AAC2" },
            { shop: "16h-20h", value: 80, color: "#A2AAC2" },
            { shop: "20h-00h", value: 80, color: "#A2AAC2" }
        ]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return [data];

};

export { UpdateGraph };
```

**Implementation** (my-component.js)

```
const { UpdateGraph } from "./UpdateGraph.js" // your path...

const [datas] = UpdateGraph();

return (
    <Graph key={"graph_001"} 
           h={400} w={900} 
           data={datas} 
           defaultKeys={["shop", "value"]} />
);
```

Comment: i dont see what's different here from the OP other than you've split it into two components, plus the Graph component?