# How to implement componentDidMount with hooks in React to be in line with the EsLint rule "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-hooks

According to the official React documentation, `componentDidMount` is translated in hooks as:

```
useEffect(() => {
 //code here 
},[])
```

So assuming I want to do an api call within this hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
 getActiveUser(); 
},[])
```

After adding the eslint rule `"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"`, this is a lint error. In order to silence it I can just drop the `getActiveUser` function inside the array and everything works just fine.

But does that go against the documentation? I was under the impression that the array checks for prop changes. I would like also to point out that the API call is being made without a prop/id, so I could understand the fact of having to do something like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
 getActiveUser(someId); 
},[getActiveUser, someId])
```

So what's going on here? Adding the Eslint rule mean that the array inside the effect can't be empty again?

Comment: "A common mistake is to think functions shouldn’t be dependencies. ....But the problem with simply omitting local functions is that it gets pretty hard to tell whether we’re handling all cases as the component grows!" [via](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) So you can't be sure (or can you) this function will change where do you define it in time. So, to be safe either you add it in the dependencies or define it in the `useEffect`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-do-i-fix-missing-dependency-in-react-hook-useeffect/55854902#55854902

Comment: put your function inside useEffect and Id to array only

Comment: @Shubham Khatri not a duplicate, I'm adressing a different issue here which is: Using the eslint rule, does that mean array can't be empty again?

Comment: maybe better re-think how it works and provide `getActiveUser` as a dependency. see discussion https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-470913287

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It matters where `getActiveUser` is declared.  The question doesn't specify, but I assume your component looks something like this:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const getActiveUser() => {
       //...
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getActiveUser();

    }, []) // Lint error.
    return <></>;
}
```

If instead your component looked like this, you wouldn't get a linter error:

```
const getActiveUser() => {
    //...
}
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getActiveUser(); 

    }, []) // No error
    return <></>;
}
```

So why is the first a linter error and the second not?  The point of the linter rule is to avoid issue due to stale props or state.  While `getActiveUser` is not itself a prop or state, when its defined inside the component, it may depend on props or state, which may be stale.

Consider this code:

```
const MyComponent  = ({userId}) => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
    const getActiveUser() => {
        setUserData(getData(userId)); // More realistically this would be async
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getActiveUser();
    }, []);

    //...
}
```

Even though that `useEffect` depends on the `userId` prop, it only runs once, and so the `userId` and the `userData` will be out of sync if the `userId` changes.  Maybe this is your intent, but for the purposes of the linter rule it looks like a bug.

In the case where `getActiveUser` is defined outside the component, it can't possibly (or at least not reasonably) depend on the state or props of the component, so there's no issue for the linter rule.

---

So how to fix this?  Well, if `getActiveUser` doesn't need to be defined inside the component, just move it out of the component.

Alternatively, if you're sure you only want this behavior to run when the component mounts, and that won't cause issue due to props changing (it's best to assume all props can change), then you can just disable the linter rule.

But assuming neither of those is the case...

#### A non-solution (too many effects)

As you've noted, adding `getActiveUser` to the linter array makes the issue go away:

```
const MyComponent = ({userId}) => {
    const getActiveUser() => {
       //...
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getActiveUser();

    }, [getActiveUser]) // No error... but probably not right.
    return <></>;
}
```

But `getActiveUser` is a different function instance every render, so as far as `useEffect` is concerned, the deps array changes every render, which will cause an API call after every render, which is almost certainly not what you want.

#### A fragile solution

Since the root issue in my example is that the `userId` prop might change, you could also fix this issue by adding `userId` to the `useEffect` dependencies:

```
const MyComponent = ({userId}) => {
    const getActiveUser() => {
       // Uses userId
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getActiveUser();

    // Linter is still unhappy, so:
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [userId])
    return <></>;
}
```

This behaves correctly - no extra API calls or stale data - but the linter is still unhappy: it isn't clever enough to know that we've fixed the dependency on `getActiveUser` by depending on all the things that `getActiveUser` depends on.

And this is fragile: if you add a prop or state in the future that `getActiveUser` depends on, and forget to add it here, you're going to have stale data issues.

#### A better solution

So the recommended solution is:

```
const MyComponent = ({userId}) => {
    const getActiveUsers = useCallback(() => {
        // uses userId
    }, [userId]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getActiveUser(); 

    }, [getActiveUsers]) // No error
    return <></>;
}
```

By wrapping `getActiveUsers` in `useCallback`, the function instance is only replaced when needed: when `userId` changes.  This means that the `useEffect` also only runs when needed: when `getActiveUsers` changes (which is whenever `userId` changes).

The linter is happy with this solution and if you introduce new dependencies to `getActiveUser`, you'll only need to change its `useCallback` deps, not the `useEffect`.

---

Dan Abramov's blogpost [A Complete Guide to `useEffect`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) goes into this in more detail.

Comment: This is a good SO post! Thank you for breaking this down into multiple examples.