# React: Trying to rewrite ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps) with react hook useEffect, but it fires when the app starts

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm using a componentDidUpdate function

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
     if(prevProps.value !== this.props.users){ 
        ipcRenderer.send('userList:store',this.props.users);    
}
```

to this

```
const users = useSelector(state => state.reddit.users)

    useEffect(() => {
       console.log('users changed')
       console.log({users})
    }, [users]);
```

but it  I get the message 'users changed' when I start the app. But the user state **HAS NOT** changed at all

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render

Comment: I have this exact case... hooks suck!

Comment: @A.com Hooks rule!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, that's how useEffect works. It runs after every render by default. If you supply an array as a second parameter, it will run on the first render, but then skip subsequent renders if the specified values have not changed. There is no built in way to skip the first render, since that's a pretty rare case.

If you need the code to have no effect on the very first render, you're going to need to do some extra work. You can use `useRef` to create a mutable variable, and change it to indicate once the first render is complete. For example:

```
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);
  const users = useSelector(state => state.reddit.users);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender.current) {
      isFirstRender.current = false;
    } else {
       console.log('users changed')
       console.log({users})
    }
  }, [users]);
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you could create a custom hook so you can reuse it easier. Something like this:

```
const useUpdateEffect = (callback, dependencies) => {
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender.current) {
      isFirstRender.current = false;
    } else {
      return callback();
    }

  }, dependencies);
}

// to be used like:

const users = useSelector(state => state.reddit.users);
useUpdateEffect(() => {
  console.log('users changed')
  console.log({users})
}, [users]);
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. But when I use antoher useEffect for 'guest', it still fires on startup. Is there a solution?

Comment: If you find yourself needing to do this a lot, i recommend you extract the code to a custom hook. I've edited in an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
>   of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
>   componentWillUnmount combined.

As from: [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

This, it will be invoked as the component is painted in your DOM, which is likely to be closer to `componentDidMount`.