# React: How to skip useEffect on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the `useEffect` hook inside a controlled form component to inform the parent component whenever the form content is changed by user and return the DTO of the form content. Here is my current attempt

```
const useFormInput = initialValue => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)

  const onChange = ({target}) => {
    console.log("onChange")
    setValue(target.value)
  }

  return { value, setValue, binding: { value, onChange }}
}
useFormInput.propTypes = {
  initialValue: PropTypes.any
}

const DummyForm = ({dummy, onChange}) => {

  const {value: foo, binding: fooBinding} = useFormInput(dummy.value)
  const {value: bar, binding: barBinding} = useFormInput(dummy.value)

  // This should run only after the initial render when user edits inputs
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("onChange callback")
    onChange({foo, bar})
  }, [foo, bar])

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" {...fooBinding} />
      <div>{foo}</div>

      <input type="text" {...barBinding} />
      <div>{bar}</div>
    </div>
  )
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <DummyForm dummy={{value: "Initial"}} onChange={(dummy) => console.log(dummy)} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, now the effect is ran on the first render, when the initial values are set during mount. How do I avoid that?

Here are the current logs of loading the page and subsequently editing both fields. I also wonder why I get that warning of missing dependency.

```
onChange callback
App.js:136 {foo: "Initial", bar: "Initial"}
backend.js:1 ./src/App.js
  Line 118:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'onChange'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'onChange' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
r @ backend.js:1
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:120
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:125
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:190
push../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:56
(anonymous) @ main.js:282
push../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:280
push../node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:53
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:36
App.js:99 onChange
App.js:116 onChange callback
App.js:136 {foo: "Initial1", bar: "Initial"}
App.js:99 onChange
App.js:116 onChange callback
App.js:136 {foo: "Initial1", bar: "Initial2"}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render) for an approach of how to ignore the initial render. This approach uses `useRef` to keep track of the first render.

```
  const firstUpdate = useRef(true);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (firstUpdate.current) {
      firstUpdate.current = false;
    } else {
     // do things after first render
    }
  });
```

As for the **warning** you were getting:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'onChange'

The trailing array in a hook invocation (`useEffect(() => {}, [foo]`) list the dependencies of the hook. This means if you are using a variable within the scope of the hook that can change based on changes to the component (say a property of the component) it needs to be listed there.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for something like componentDidUpdate() without going through componentDidMount(), you can write a hook like:

```
export const useComponentDidMount = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = true;
  }, []);
  return ref.current;
};
```

In your component you can use it like:

```
const isComponentMounted = useComponentDidMount();

useEffect(() => {
 if(isComponentMounted) {
  // Do something
 }
}, [someValue])
```

In your case it will be:

```
const DummyForm = ({dummy, onChange}) => {
  const isComponentMounted = useComponentDidMount();
  const {value: foo, binding: fooBinding} = useFormInput(dummy.value)
  const {value: bar, binding: barBinding} = useFormInput(dummy.value)

  // This should run only after the initial render when user edits inputs
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isComponentMounted) {
      console.log("onChange callback")
      onChange({foo, bar})
    }
  }, [foo, bar])

  return (
    // code
  )
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I create a simple hook for this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-skip-first-render?file=index.js

It is based on paruchuri-p

```
const useSkipFirstRender = (fn, args) => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      console.log('running')
      return fn();
    }
  }, args)

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true
  }, [])
}
```

The first effect is the main one as if you were using it in your component. It will run, discover that isMounted isn't `true` and will just skip doing anything.

Then after the bottom `useEffect` is run, it will change the `isMounted` to `true` - thus when the component is forced into a re-render. It will allow the first useEffect to render normally.

It just makes a nice self-encapsulated re-usable hook. Obviously you can change the name, it's up to you.

Comment: I feel sorry for using ref for such a simple task. I hope React team will tweak the hook API to consider this issue which I believe is very common.

Comment: They did write it on their docs saying that is a very rare case and hence not implemented yet.

Comment: yeah it is an interesting case, I can't say I've needed it once I got my head round hooks - in the very first instance I needed it for sure

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) to run use effect after mount.

```
const useEffectAfterMount = (cb, dependencies) => {
  const mounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current) {
      return cb();
    }
    mounted.current = false;
  }, dependencies); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
};
```

Here is the `typescript` version:

```
const useEffectAfterMount = (cb: EffectCallback, dependencies: DependencyList | undefined) => {
  const mounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current) {
      return cb();
    }
    mounted.current = false;
  }, dependencies); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
};
```

Example:

```
useEffectAfterMount(() => {
  console.log("onChange callback")
  onChange({foo, bar})
}, [count])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need a `useEffect` here in the first place. Your form inputs should almost certainly be [controlled input components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) where the current value of the form is provided as a prop and the form simply provides an `onChange` handler. The current values of the form should be stored in `<App>`, otherwise how ever will you get access to the value of the form from somewhere else in your application?

```
const DummyForm = ({valueOne, updateOne, valueTwo, updateTwo}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={valueOne} onChange={updateOne} />
      <div>{valueOne}</div>

      <input type="text" value={valueTwo} onChange={updateTwo} />
      <div>{valueTwo}</div>
    </div>
  )
}


function App() {
  const [inputOne, setInputOne] = useState("");
  const [inputTwo, setInputTwo] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <DummyForm
          valueOne={inputOne}
          updateOne={(e) => {
            setInputOne(e.target.value);
          }}
          valueTwo={inputTwo}
          updateTwo={(e) => {
            setInputTwo(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Much cleaner, simpler, flexible, utilizes standard React patterns, and no `useEffect` required.

Comment: Consider the case where I need to iterate array of entities and render a form for each one. Parent component should keep track of which entities have changed and access their current state for batch update. I also want to utilize the generic form input hook for reduced boilerplate.