# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component after update context and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having a problem which needs your helps

I have a `changeProfile` function which will be executed after `onClick` in `/editpage`

```
const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = appContext.userLogin;
const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState<UserProfile>({
    name: userLogin.name,
    ....
});
const changeProfile = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    post(API)
        .then(() => {
            setUserLogin({
                ...userLogin,
                name: userProfile.name,
            });
            router.push('/mypage');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setEditError(error[0]);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
};
```

**context.tsx**

```
const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState({
     email: '',
     name: '',
     ....
});
```

after page redirects to `/mypage`, console logs warning error as title and it only logs warning at the first time (if I back to `/editpage` and `changeProfile` one more time, console logs nothing in`/mypage`)

I have tried to `redirect` after `setUserLogin` done as  code below but it's not working

```
const changeProfile = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    post(API)
        .then(() => {
            setUserLogin({
                ...userLogin,
                name: userProfile.name,
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setEditError(error[0]);
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
};

const firstUpdate = useRef(true);
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (firstUpdate.current) {
        firstUpdate.current = false;

        return;
    }
    console.log(userLogin); //already updated
    router.push('/mypage');
}, [userLogin]);
```

Thanks for reading!

PS: Problem can be solved with

```
setTimeout(() => {
    router.push('/mypage');
}, 1000);
```

but its absolutely not a right choice

Comment: Can you include the code for `setUserLogin`?

Comment: Do you want to handle warning? 
Or the redirection part?

Comment: @UtsavPatel handling warning is what I need

Comment: This is most likely happening because of `useLayoutEffect`.
Can you replace it with `useEffect`?

Comment: yes, I have tried, i use `useLayoutEffect` to [Make React useEffect hook not run on initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render/53254028#53254028)

Comment: So, even after using `useEffect` you are facing same error?

Comment: @UtsavPatel yesss

Answer (score 1):

As the warning suggests, because your API code is asynchronous, if you redirect away from the page too fast, the setState may occur after the component has already been unmounted. What you can do, is use the `callback` argument of `setState` (assuming you're calling `setState` somewhere in the `setUserLogin` function), to redirect *after* the state update has already been completed.

**Edit**: You could try adding another state variable to your context to signify that an update has been performed, something like `updated: false` and then with your `setUserLogin` call:

```
setUserLogin({
    ...userLogin,
    name: userProfile.name,
    updated: true
});
```

Then you can use the `useEffect` hook to check for this condition and then redirect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userLogin.updated) {
        router.push('/mypage');
    }
})
```

Then at some point, you would have to reset this variable to `false`. However, now that I know your `setUserLogin` is coming from the `AppContext` component, I think the issue is that this component is getting unmounted when it shouldn't be. Make sure you're rendering this component high enough in the component tree so that the `mypage` you redirect to still has this `AppContext` mounted

**Edit 2**: A good approach to prevent this error is by adding a guard to a component class, which keeps track of whether the component is mounted or not. Something like this:

```
class AppContext extends Component {
    _mounted = False;

    componentDidMount() {
        this._mounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._mounted = false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, when you call `setState` or the update function from `useState`, you can first check to see if the component is mounted or not before trying to update:

```
if (AppContext._mounted) {
    setUserLogin({
        ...userLogin,
        name: userProfile.name,
        updated: true
    });
}
```

However, in your case, this may prevent the information from being updated as you expect, since the component is unmounting, which is why I think the issue lies with why the component is unmounting

Comment: thanks, I updated question and you can see my `setUserLogin`

Comment: ahh no, you can see I updated state in `context.tsx` and info `userLogin` be used in `/mypage` and another pages

Comment: @iamhuynq yup I realized that after looking at your context code, that's why I removed the comment

Comment: @iamhuynq also, where is the `useLayoutEffect` function coming from?

Comment: it from `import { useLayoutEffect } from 'React'`,  you can see here [Make React useEffect hook not run on initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render/53254028#53254028)

Comment: thank you, but it seem not working because I did `console.log(userLogin)` inside `useLayoutEffect`, I can see `userLogin` already updated by `setUserLogin`

Comment: @iamhuynq hmm ok can you also include the code which shows where this component and the `AppContext` component  are rendered? As I mentioned in the last part of my answer, an unintentional unmounting of the component could be causing this

Comment: @iamhuynq I also added an edit which will prevent this warning, but it may also prevent the information from being updated as you expect