# React hook only when props change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do something
}, [stringProp]);
```

`stringProp` is by default an empty string.

When I change `stringProp` to `foobar` the effect runs.

But,

the `useEffect` also runs when the component first mounts, which I don't want.

How to run an effect hook ONLY when props change?

Comment: looks like there's a good discussion of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem many times using a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```
const firstRun = useRef(true);
...
useEffect(() => {
  // skip the first run
  if (firstRun.current) {
    firstRun.current = false;
    return;
  }

  // do stuff
}, [stringProp]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop `useEffect` run when the component first mounted, but you can do the condition checking to run your code inside it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Only run when stringProp has value, you might have different condition, add them there
  if(stringProp){
    // do something
  }
}, [stringProp]);
```

Updated: If you might set stringProp back to the initial value, you can do use `useRef` to control first time run like this

```
const isFirstTimeOfUseEffect = useRef(true)
useEffect(() => {
  // Only run when stringProp has value, you might have different condition, add them there
  if(!firstUseEffectRun.current){
    // do something
  }else{
    firstUseEffectRun.current = false
  }
}, [stringProp]);
```

Comment: the problem with this is that if `stringProp` is set back to an empty string at some point, the `do something` won't fire...so this is not a perfect solution

Comment: @SethLutske Thanks for your comment, I updated my answer to have better solution