# React Hook Form: Making append() Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

React Hook Forms provides a method `append()` on `useFieldArray` to add more rows to the dynamic fields array.

I'm able to use `append()`. However, I want to execute another function immediately after calling `append()`. But that's not happening. Instead, the next function gets called before `append()` is completed.

How can I change this behavour and ensure that the next function will be called only after append() is completed?

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray

In the following example:

```
onClick={() => {
                    console.log('fields 1', fields)
                    append({
                      item: 
                        {
                          id: 1, 
                          name: 'test'
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('fields 2', fields)

                    }}>
```

In the above example, the length of fields remains the same. It doesn't increase. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, `append` relies on a call to a `useState` setter (see [the source](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/3c774534083e1b6f8d2f5ef7b65690ef380c6122/src/useFieldArray.ts#L70)), which means that `fields` is a `useState` stateful value and you'll only see the updated value on the next render.

To perform effects in response to state changes, use the `useEffect` hook. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). In your case, you'd want to do something like

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFieldArray } from 'react-hook-form';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray(...);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this callback will run once on initial render and
    // then again whenever `fields` is updated
    console.log('fields 2', fields);
  }, [fields]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {
          console.log('fields 1', fields);
          append({ item: { id: 1, name: 'test' } });
        }}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the above example, the component will print

```
fields 2 []
```

on initial render, and then

```
fields 1 []
fields 2 [{ id: 1, name: 'test' }]
```

once you click the button to append a new field. If you need to differentiate between initial render and subsequent updates, you can check that the value of `fields` has changed from its initial value (probably `[]`).

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. But the useEffect be called for any change in fields, even if user updates value in a field in the form? What if I wanted to make it run only when a new object is added fields and not otherwise. Is that possible?

Comment: Actually I tried and it updates only when a new object is added to array. So, it works well for me. But just want to make sure that this indeed is how it will work.

Comment: Also, is it possible to not make it run on initial render?

Comment: You're correct, it will only run when the external shape of `fields` changes (when an element is added or removed), not when a field's value is modified. If you want to avoid the run on initial render, you can track whether or not you've rendered in a ref and conditionally run based on that (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254028/885098)).