# React.js useState() is not getting any values;

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am learning React.js and got problem in a place.

I am fetching data from localhost:4000/products (i.e)

[Here is my localhost:4000/products page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1eAP.png)

And I am doing the backend query in node.js

Here is the page:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");
app.use(cors());

const selectallquery = "SELECT * FROM users";

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "Sakthi@1234",
    database: "reactSql",
});



app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    res.send('Hello Sakthi')
});

app.get("/products/add", (req,res)=> {
    const { name } = req.query;
    console.log(name);
    const insertquery = `INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('${name}')`;
    db.query(insertquery, (err,result)=> {
        if(err){
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else{
            return res.send("Successfully added...`")
        }
    });
});

app.get("/products", (req,res)=> {
    db.query(selectallquery, (err,result)=> {
        if (err){
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else{
            return res.send(result)
        }
    });

});

app.listen(4000,()=> {
    console.log("Running on server 4000")
});
```

And here is my React.js page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios  from "axios";


function Login() {
    const [names, setnames] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=> {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/products")
    .then(res => {
        
    
        if (res !== ""){
           
            setnames([...names,res.data.name])
             
           
        }
        
    })
    
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
},[])



return (
    <div>
        {
            names
        }
    </div>
)
}

export default Login
```

The state names is not set with any value.
And it is not showing any values:

[Its the page showing nothing :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKw29.png)

And Also i want to know how to make the useEffect hook not to render on first render(componentWillMount) and only  to render at last(componentDidMount).

[This is my console of res:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hadlY.png)

Comment: can you show console of `res`?

Comment: Yeah sure sir...

Comment: I added it in the last line sir.

Comment: names is an array? Do you want show all names from API?

Comment: Yeah sir. I need to show all names

Comment: data.name is undefine, right? May you should map array obj to arr names

Comment: But is says res.map is not a function sir..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.data` is an array, so if you want to only keep names, you need to map on it to only store names to your state

```
setnames(names => [...names, ...res.data.map(({name}) => name)])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to update `setnames` because `res.data` is an array so you can not use `res.data.name`:

```
setnames(res.data)
```

And in return, you need to use `map` to show name:

```
{names.map((item) => (
    <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
  ))}
```

Comment: Sir, after updating the setnames with res.data while consoling it return only an empty array.

Comment: No issues sir :).   It also returns an empty array but when we use `names` as dependency, rather than the first render it returns the array sir, but it doesn't while the first rendering.

Comment: I think this is the case where you want to use async for fetching in useEffect and only then trying to get anything back.

Comment: How to get that effect sir?

Answer (score -1):

You can use useRef to set the node not to render at the first time.

[Make React useEffect hook not run on initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render)