# Only Pre-render first page with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, swr

I'm trying to combine pre-rendering with `getStaticProps()` and client-side rendering with a regular `userSwr()` data fetch, and running into trouble.

**Context:**
I have a list of results that can span multiple pages, as well as be filtered by various attributes (like number of bedrooms, rent, etc). A paginated and filtered url might look like `/listings?page=2&bedrooms=3`

I want to pre-render the first page of unfiltered results by using `getStaticProps()`, so the initial pageload is fast. From there, I want a user to be able to make data calls from the client, using the [`useSwr()` hook](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#swr), for additional pages or filtered results.

**Question:**
What's the best way to combine these data fetching models? Everything I can find suggests pre-rendering every page of results, but I don't want to pre-render every permutation of pages and filters.

**Current idea:**
My current idea is to

- Fetch the first page of data in `getStaticProps` and pass it in as a prop
- Use a hook to fetch additional pages and filtered results from the client
- Use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254028/40871) to keep the hook from running on the initial render.

Is there a better way to do only pre-render the first page, but client-side render after that?

Comment: Your idea makes sense. Have you tried implementing it? Did you run into any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar to this. I don't block the initial run of the hook though. I want to get the SSG version up so users don't wait and it can get easily spidered for SEO. I don't want to encounter scenarios where a file that is on Page 1 of SSG is also on page 2 of queried data so a user hits next page and sees the same content.  This is an extreme example, in general SSG on my sites is only 5-10 minutes behind updates to live data.