# Run useEffect only on button click

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am making a feature of liking and disliking a post where the data for post is coming from backend

```
  const blog = {
    likeStatus: false
  }
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState(blog.likeStatus);

  const likeAPI = (status) => {
    console.log(status);
  } 
  useEffect(() => {
    let status = liked ? 'LIKE' : 'DISLIKE';
    likeAPI(status); // API for liking and disliking a post
  }, [liked])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={{backgroundColor: liked ? 'green' : 'white'}}
        onClick={() => setLiked(!liked)}
      >
        Like
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

This is the code for the feature

I want to run `useEffect` only when the like `button` is clicked but the `useEffect` also runs initially and the like status is send to the backend resulting in wrong data

Can someone help me with this ?

Any other logic is appreciated

Comment: You should just extract the body of useEffect to be a separate function and then call it from both useEffect and onClick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make React useEffect hook not run on initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render)

Answer (score 3):

You do it without using a useEffect hook, like this:

```
const blog = {
  likeStatus: false,
};
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(blog.likeStatus);

const likeAPI = (status) => {
  console.log(status);
};

const handleClick = (liked) => {
  setLiked(liked);
  let status = liked ? "LIKE" : "DISLIKE";
  likeAPI(status); // API for liking and disliking a post
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <button
      style={{ backgroundColor: liked ? "green" : "white" }}
      onClick={() => handleClick(!liked)}
    >
      Like
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Will this work ? Since useState is asynchronous, it will not update the state immediately

Comment: Yes it will. Didn't you try it ? because the same state used in setLiked and as param of the likeAPi function

Comment: Oh yeah ! I got it what you are doing. Its really dumb of me to not think that