# What is the good practice way to prevent a useEffect from triggering on initial render?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

My current solution involves an extra `useState` which holds a boolean variable to signal whether it is the initial render of the component or not.

This does not seem like good practice.

What is the standard way to archive this?

I use react hooks, not classes.

```
  const [init_render, set_init_render] = useState(true);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!init_render) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }, [dependency]);
```

Comment: If you don't have a dependency, toggling a boolean value seems fine to me.

Comment: Perhaps it makes more sense to use a `useRef()` instead of `useState()`, so you don't trigger rerenders. But, besides that, that's probably how I would do it as well.

Comment: I think this answers yours, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render

Comment: all of those solutions seem like what I am currently doing, which I guess is the best way then.