# React - prevent calling useEffect for the first mount

Tags: reactjs, render, react-functional-component, preventdefault

I want to prevent calling my `useEffect` on the first `mount`.
how can I do this?
I want the `best practice`.
I don't want to use `if condition`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(5);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Counter </h1>
      <div> {count} </div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}> click to increase </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render

Comment: You can skip a render in useEffect only by using an if statement. Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
It should be handled by `useLayoutEffect` and `useRef`

```
import { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(5);

  const firstUpdate = useRef(true);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (firstUpdate.current) {
      firstUpdate.current = false;
      return;
    }
    console.log(count);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Counter </h1>
      <div> {count} </div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}> click to increase </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```