# Local storage gets cleared every time I refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm building a todo List in React, and using Local Storage to save my todos so every time I refresh, they stay displayed.

The issue I'm facing is that whenever I refresh my page, the local storage gets cleared, which is weird because when I've used local storage using Vanilla js and usually got it to do what I wanted. Anyway, here is a snippet of my code:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    getLocalTodos();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() =>{
    filterHandler();
    saveLocalTodos();
  }, [todos, status]);

  const filterHandler = () =>{
    switch(status){
      case 'completed':
        setFilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed))
        break;
      case 'todo':
        console.log("herex")

        setFilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed))
        break;
      default:
        setFilteredTodos(todos);
        break;
    }
  }

  const saveLocalTodos = () => {
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))

  }

  const getLocalTodos = () =>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('todos') === null){
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
    }else{
      let todoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"))
      setTodos(todoLocal)
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are using `saveLocalTodos` on load, when `todos` is `[]`

Comment: 1. It's not me who downvoted. 2. You can always remove the question to get your reputation back. 3. Asking a rookie question that will not help anyone in the future isn't the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Muath_01 FYI i haven't downvoted. But you can always try putting logs in your code to see what is happening. That will definitely take less time and effort than posting a question here, and will for sure make you a better developer

Answer (score 1):

Put a log to see when this [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) runs :

```
  useEffect(() =>{
    filterHandler();
    saveLocalTodos();
  }, [todos, status]);
```

The callback here will run on the very first render (calling `saveLocalTodos`) and after that on every render when either todos or status changes.

Since `todos` state variable is empty initially, it will empty data after first mount.

Comment: I understand that it runs every time todos and status changes, but that's what I want. What does the second part mean?

Comment: When it runs on first time, then `todos` is an empty array right? So `saveLocalTodos` is called which will save an empty array in your storage.

Comment: Is there a way to make saveLocalTodos not run on reload? I need it to assign the todos into the local storage everytime I add a new Todo.

Comment: A hack is to use a ref variable and set some value after first render. Check that value and only then run your second useEffect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render

Comment: Ok, is this caused by a new update to React?, this tutorial has the exact same thing I have but it's working for him. Skip to minute 1:31:00 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCA4qpQDZD8