# How to disable Strict Mode in React 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-strictmode

Simply, how can I disable Strict Mode in React 18? I'm using React 18 with create-react-app.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look for this code in index.js and remove the outer element:

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
```

> **Note**:
>
> Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not
> impact the production build.

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Answer (score 6):

To disable strict mode in React 18, you need to look-up for the below-given code in **index.js**.

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
```

Now Remove the outer element and your code will look like this:

```
<App/>
```

**This will disable strict mode.**