# Alert when counter reaches 0 fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to add a feature to my simple Counter (React) App which alerts when `counter` reaches 0  `onClick` increase or decrease button. But alert always late for 1 click. How can I fix it?
Here is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function handleIncrement() {
    setCounter((oldState) => oldState + 1);
    if (counter === 0) alert('it is 0');
  }

  function handleDecrement() {
    setCounter((oldState) => oldState - 1);
    if (counter === 0) alert('it is 0');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>increment</button>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to see alert exactly when I see 0 on the screen. But the code above shown alert only after the counter passed zero.

Comment: What does your `setCounter` do and why you don't use `counter++` and `counter--`?

Comment: This is happening bcoz *setCounter* is async operation. to fix this you can wrap alert function inside the *setCounter's callback*.

Comment: Or you can also use useEffect

Comment: The counter is initialised to zero. Do you want it to alert immediately, or only if a button is clicked, and is _then_ zero?

Comment: @Andy I wanted to do it happens when clicking button. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening bcoz setCounter is async operation.
We can fix this using this two ways

1. wrap alert function inside the **setCounter's callback**.

```
function handleIncrement() {
    
  setCounter((oldState) => {
    
    if (oldState + 1 === 0) {
      alert('it is');
    }
    
  return oldState + 1;
  });  
}
    
    
function handleDecrement() {
    
  setCounter((oldState) => {
    
    if (oldState - 1 === 0) {
      alert('it is 0');
    }
    
    return oldState - 1;
    
  });
}
```

2. you can also use **useEffect** to achieve this

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (counter === 0) {
    alert('it is 0');
  }

}, [counter]);

    
function handleIncrement() {
  setCounter(counter + 1);
}

    
function handleDecrement() {
  setCounter(counter - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect`, and a `ref`. The ref stores whether it's the first update or not. The `useEffect` checks to see if it's the first update. If it is it resets the `ref` to `false`, otherwise it logs/alerts the `counter` state.

(Cribbed slightly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render).)

```js
const { useEffect, useState, useRef } = React;

function Example() {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const firstUpdate = useRef(true);

  function handleIncrement() {
    setCounter(prev => prev + 1);
  }

  function handleDecrement() {
    setCounter(prev => prev - 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstUpdate.current) {
      firstUpdate.current = false;
      return;
    }
    if (counter === 0) console.log('it is');
  }, [counter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>increment</button>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>decrement</button>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's okay, because react renders in frames like when you watch a movie or play a video game, at the current frame where you call this line

```
    setCounter((oldState) => oldState - 1);
```

`counter` still `1` not `0`, so you need to wait until react do the re-render, then the next render start with `counter` being `0`, but the alert you defined inside click handler won't be called automatically, you didn't call it, you made that call inside the `onClick` handler which will not be called until button clicked(obviously)

so the problem is not with how react re-render the state, it's where to put your `alert` or in other words how to consume your state

a simple fix to your solution is to put `alert` outside the call, in the component body

```
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function handleIncrement() {
    setCounter((oldState) => oldState + 1);
  }

  function handleDecrement() {
    setCounter((oldState) => oldState - 1);
  }

  if (counter === 0) alert('it is 0');


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>increment</button>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Anyway it's not a good idea to have `alert` called inside the body of a component so I'd assume you have an alert component that's shown to the user when the counter reach 0

```
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function handleIncrement() {
    setCounter((oldState) => oldState + 1);
  }

  function handleDecrement() {
    setCounter((oldState) => oldState - 1);
  }

  if(counter == 0){
    return <Alert message="counter is 0 now"/>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>increment</button>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={handleDecrement}>decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for solving your problem is to handle states update inside the `useEffect` hook.
Your issue happened because of `useState` async hook.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

function handleIncrement() {
  setCounter((oldState) => oldState + 1);
}

function handleDecrement() {
  setCounter((oldState) => oldState - 1);
}

useEffect(()=>{
  if(counter === 0) {
    alert('it is')
  }
}, [counter])

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleIncrement}>increment</button>
    <div>{counter}</div>
    <button onClick={handleDecrement}>decrement</button>
  </div>
 );
}
```