# How should I trigger a useEffect immediately after a setState in the same onChange listener?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I have a number input that is linked to a state variable.
`onChange` of the input I would like to change the state and trigger a subscribe in `useEffect`.

[Here's the working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gusujy?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx&title=React%20Starter)

This is the gist of it -

```
<input
  type="number"
  value={freeHours}
  onChange={(event) => {
     setFreeHours(+event.target.value);
     updateHours(null);
  }}
  // onBlur={updateHours}
/>
```

Calling the `updateHours()` (useEffect trigger) immediately after `setFreeHours()` (setState) fails because the component rerenders. If I move `updateHours()` to onBlur it works fine since the subscription gets triggered after the rerender.

How do I achieve both of these in the onChange listener?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to update your logic** : initialized freeHours as useEffect dependency .

```
useEffect(() => {
    updateHours( null );
}, [freeHours])
```

***Your code should be like this:***

```
<input
  type="number"
  value={freeHours}
  onChange={(event) => {
     setFreeHours(+Number(event.target.value));
  }}
/>
```

**Or, Try this way:**

```
 <input
      type="number"
      value={freeHours}
      onChange={(event) => {
         setFreeHours(prev=> prev + Number(event.target.value));
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, adding the useEffect with dep freeHours was triggering the update on inital load as well. But I was able to create a custom hook from this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57941438/4327976