React context useEffect not triggered when dependency is called from within another component
In a component i use a context and its state functions and then call the setReviewConfig
const { reviewConfig, setReviewConfig } = useContext(ReviewConfigContext);
// other code
console.log('Running removeYelpConfig ... modified reviewConfig')
        console.log(reviewConfig)
        setReviewConfig(reviewConfig) // this is in the other component where i call the setter

The console log is running so i know what is being passed to setReviewConfig and the reviewConfig is indeed modified.
In the context I have ...
const [reviewConfig,setReviewConfig] = useState(null)

....
useEffect(() => {
            if( reviewConfig !== null){
                console.log("ReviewConfigContext reviewConfig, ")
                console.log(reviewConfig)
...
            }else{
                console.log("ReviewConfigContext not updating reviewConfig ")
            }

    }, [reviewConfig, setReviewConfig])

But when the component modifies reviewConfig or calls that function setReviewConfig the useEffect in the context is not run, i know because the console.log in the useEffect are not run.
I have deployed an extract of the app on this replit https://replit.com/@bizmate/SetterComponentCall#src/components/YelpConfigDisplay.jsx
it runs also from https://c6c0f2a9-1f10-43c0-8c9a-06ae0dc27fd4-00-1bpt8cb4rltiq.janeway.replit.dev/
while i am in the workspace (most likely you will not be able to run it unless you fork it or I am running it).
Just to confirm, the modified reviewConfig is indeed modified correctly in the component as per console.log but the useEffect of the context is not run after setReviewConfig is being called.
What am I missing? Is any of the above bad practice?
My ultimate goal is to do any further networking or state change related operation on reviewConfig in the context so that any component can call the setter or modify the variable but does not need to implement network calls etc, as these will be handled by the context

https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#copying-objects-with-the-spread-syntax

reviewConfig.sourceConfigs.splice(
  reviewConfig.sourceConfigs.findIndex((el) => el.sourceType.name == "Yelp", 1),
);
console.log("Running removeYelpConfig ... modified reviewConfig");
console.log(reviewConfig);
setReviewConfig(reviewConfig);

One of the core assumptions that react makes is that state is immutable. When you set state, react compares the old state and the new state using Object.is (similar to ===). Since it's the same object before and after, it looks to react like it has not changed. Thus the render gets skipped and the effect does not run.
You must create a new state instead of mutating the old one.
setReviewConfig(prev => {
  const next = {
    ...prev, // Copy the old object into a new one
    sourceConfigs: prev.sourceConfigs.filter(el => el.sourceType.name != "yelp")
  }
  return next;
});


Thanks i think the above is a good explaination, I must say how React works does not resonate with me... also i read this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/clone-an-object-in-javascript/
One part that does not seem to work is that if I only have the setter in the useEffect dependency, the useEffect is still not triggered despite cloning the object. If i set also the reviewConfig in the useEffect then it will run at load time ... I need to find a way to run it only when the setter is called and not a load time

useEffect is designed so that it will always run on the first render. And then in addition it will run if of the dependencies changes. If you need to skip running the effect on the first render, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253940/make-react-useeffect-hook-not-run-on-initial-render

will the useEffect run If I have only the setter in the dependencies array of the useEffect, ie [setReviewConfig]?
Currently the useEffect is not running even if i clone the object and pass it to the setter.

setReviewConfig never changes; it is always the exact same function reference. So putting it in the dependency array will have no effect. If you want the effect to run when the reviewConfig changes, you need to put reviewConfig in the dependency array.
