# React Hooks and Component Lifecycle Equivalent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What are the equivalents of the  `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle hooks using React hooks like `useEffect`?

Comment: React documentation on skipping elements https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects. Touches on the solutions given below about componentDidMount with []

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### `componentDidMount`

Pass an empty array as the second argument to `useEffect()` to run only the callback on mount only.

```js
function ComponentDidMount() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>componentDidMount: {count} times</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <ComponentDidMount />
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

### `componentDidUpdate`

`componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render. `useEffect` runs on every render including the first. So if you want to have a strict equivalent as `componentDidUpdate`, you have to use `useRef` to determine if the component has been mounted once. If you want to be even stricter, use `useLayoutEffect()`, but it fires synchronously. In most cases, `useEffect()` should be sufficient.

This [answer is inspired by Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254028/1751946), all credit goes to him.

```js
function ComponentDidUpdate() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const isFirstUpdate = React.useRef(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstUpdate.current) {
      isFirstUpdate.current = false;
      return;
    }

    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>componentDidUpdate: {count} times</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ComponentDidUpdate />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

### `componentWillUnmount`

Return a callback in useEffect's callback argument and it will be called before unmounting.

```js
function ComponentWillUnmount() {
  function ComponentWillUnmountInner(props) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        console.log('componentWillUnmount');
      };
    }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        <p>componentWillUnmount</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      {count % 2 === 0 ? (
        <ComponentWillUnmountInner count={count} />
      ) : (
        <p>No component</p>
      )}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <ComponentWillUnmount />
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer, for anyone that may not understand why the [] works for componentDidMount, this tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53253411/611628

Answer (score 17):

From [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
>   of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
>   componentWillUnmount combined.

By that saying they mean:

**componentDidMount** is sort of `useEffect(callback, [])`

**componentDidUpdate** is sort of `useEffect(callback, [dep1, dep2, ...])` - the array of deps tell React: *"if one of the deps is change, run the callback after rendering"*.

**componentDidMount + componentDidUpdate** is sort of `useEffect(callback)`

**componentWillUnmount** is sort of the returned function from the callback:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    /* some code */
    return () => { 
      /* some code to run when rerender or unmount */
    }
)
```

With the help of [Dan Abramov](https://mobile.twitter.com/dan_abramov)'s phrasing from his [blog](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/), and some additions of my own:

While you can use those hooks, it’s not an exact equivalent. Unlike `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, it will **capture** props and state. So even inside the callbacks, you’ll see the props and state of the specific render (which means in `componentDidMount` the initial props and state). If you want to see “latest” something, you can write it to a ref. But there’s usually a simpler way to structure the code so that you don’t have to.
The returned function which supposes to be alternative to `componentWillUnmount` also is not an exact equivalent, since the function will run every time the component will re-render and when the component will unmount.
Keep in mind that the mental model for effects is different from component lifecycles, and trying to find their exact equivalents may confuse you more than help. To get productive, you need to “think in effects”, and their mental model is closer to implementing synchronization than to responding to lifecycle events.

Example from Dan's blog:

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`You clicked ${count} times`);
    }, 3000);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

If we use the class implementation:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`You clicked ${this.state.count} times`);
  }, 3000);
}
```

[image]

`this.state.count` always points at the **latest** count rather than the one belonging to a particular render.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that information about it capturing the state/props of that render. That is interesting. So far I only see this as a good thing and struggling to think of any gotchas with the way useEffect handles this case.

Comment: +1 for the example showing captured state/props. I'll certainly file that for when I come across a situation where eventual consistency between data is expected asynchronously

Answer (score 14):

**For Simple Explanation, I would like to show a visual reference**

[image]

As we can see simply in the above picture that for -

**componentDidMount :**

```
useEffect(() => {        
   console.log('componentWillMount');
}, []);
```

**componentDidUpdate :**

```
useEffect(() => {        
   console.log('componentWillUpdate- runs on every update');
});

useEffect(() => {        
   console.log('componentWillUpdate - runs if dependency value changes ');
},[Dependencies]);
```

**componentwillUnmount :**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        console.log('componentWillUnmount');
    };
   }, []);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good summary from the [React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-lifecycle-methods-correspond-to-hooks) listing Hooks equivalents for class lifecycle methods:

> `constructor`: Function components don’t need a constructor. You can initialize the state in the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) call. If computing the initial state is expensive, you can pass a function to `useState`.
>
> `getDerivedStateFromProps`: Schedule an update [while rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops) instead.
>
> `shouldComponentUpdate`: See React.memo [below](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate).
>
> `render`: This is the function component body itself.
>
> `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, `componentWillUnmount`: The [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) Hook can express all combinations of these (including [less](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-skip-an-effect-on-updates) [common](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-run-an-effect-only-on-updates) cases).
>
> `componentDidCatch` and `getDerivedStateFromError`: There are **no** Hook equivalents for these methods yet, but they will be added soon.

---

#### [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

```
useEffect(() => { /*effect code*/ }, []);
```

`[]` will make the effect only run once at mount time. Usually you better [specify your dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies). To have the same layout timings as `componentDidMount`, have a look at [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) (not needed in most cases).

#### [`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

```
useEffect(() => { /*effect code*/ ; return ()=> { /*cleanup code*/ } }, [deps]);
```

`componentWillUnmount` corresponds to an effect with [cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

#### [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-run-an-effect-only-on-updates)

```
const mounted = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  if (!mounted.current) mounted.current = true;
  else {
    // ... on componentDidUpdate 
  }
});
```

To have the same layout timings as `componentDidUpdate`, have a look at [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) (not needed in most cases). See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255951/equivalent-to-componentdidupdate-using-react-hooks) for a more detailed look at `componentDidUpdate` hook equivalents.