# unable to update state using react useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-hooks

I am learning react `hooks`. In my code I have set the initial values  for plotting map as

```
//map state
const [mapData, setMapData] = useState(
    { lat: 40.712776, lng: -74.0059, zoom: 5 }
);
```

In the `useEffect()` call back I am loading the map once

```
useEffect(() => {
    initMap();
}, []); // run once
```

Inside the `initMap()` there is `map.on()` method to get the updated geo locations. The `initMap()` is

```
const initMap = () => {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer,
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [mapData.lng, mapData.lat],
        zoom: mapData.zoom
    }); // load the map with init values

    // update the `mapData` as map move
    map.on('moveend', () => {
        const { lng, lat } = map.getCenter(); // logs the updated lat and lon
        setMapData({ lat: lat.toFixed(4), lng: lng.toFixed(4), zoom: map.getZoom().toFixed(2) }); // suppose to set the updated value
        console.log(mapData); // not logging updated values!
    });
}
```

The `setMapData()` is not setting the state. But the `map.on` is called and is logging the values.

Comment: How do you know that the state is not being set? `setState` is asnychronous. It is only guaranteed to be available on another hook that reacts to it.

Comment: See answer from Chris here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265255/react-usestate-hook-event-handler-using-initial-state

Answer (score 2):

This is also the case for useSelector. 
I don't believe React Hooks is being supported by Mapbox in this way.
I have event handlers I add onto my map and those handlers cannot access the current values of the component's useState/useSelector. These values are always the values they were when the event handlers were added to the map. 
I have resorted to adding another state that triggers useEffects instead of handling it all in my event handler.

edit:
It was brought to my attention that you can use redux's 'useStore' hook to grab the current redux store even in the Mapbox event handlers!
It's tougher to test, however, bc you have to mock the 'useStore' manually. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: I came across this comment by mistake and my issue was not even related to the question, but your answer made me realize that I can use `useSelector` instead and avoid `useStore` - something that I'll have to research further, but it was a huge help and great starting point to learn something, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous, updated state may or may not be available to statements following it.

Use an effect hook that runs on a mapData update to react to changes.

```
useEffect(() => console.log(mapData), [mapData])
```

Comment: Avin is correct. By adding `mapData` to the array, react will call `useEffect()` when this value changes (and the initial mount).

Comment: This solved the issue [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53406363/11566024](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53406363/11566024)

Comment: What's wrong with this one? This is exactly what the spec says.