# Can't use useRef as componentDidUpdate replacement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch, useRef } from 'react-redux'

const mounted = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mounted', mounted)
        console.log('useEffect props:', props)
```

I have a functional component and trying to take advantage of hooks to use componentDidUpdate, in my onSubmit function I fire a dispatch to call and API, and I need to see what is the resulting payload of that API, which is stored in redux. But I get the error above?

I found this answer which said to use useRef [Equivalent to componentDidUpdate using React hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255951/equivalent-to-componentdidupdate-using-react-hooks)

Answer (score 3):

useRef is a React hook. Change to:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should access your ref using `mounted.current`.  Since you are not initializing it a value, it will return `undefined`.

If you are assigning your ref to a JSX element, you will not be able to access it until the DOM has loaded.  In that case, I would suggest using the `useLayoutEffect` hook, since it will not run until the DOM has loaded.