# componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate together using useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

The thing is i want to run some logic only when mounting and also i want to run some other logic when every render/updates. How can we achieve this using hooks in a functional component. If it was a class component i could've use componentDidMount for one time execution and componentDidUpdate for every render.

Comment: I think you can use a variation of  the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53406363/7351882

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent to componentDidUpdate using React hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255951/equivalent-to-componentdidupdate-using-react-hooks)

Comment: These are like some extra logic we adding to achieve such usecase, other than this react itself not providing other options right ?

Answer (score 2):

### **Here is a complete explanation:**

**Equivalent to componentDidMount**

```
useEffect(() => {
  // same as componentDidMount
}, []);
```

**Equivalent to componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate**

```
useEffect(() => {
  // same as componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate
});
```

**This will be called on change of state variable**

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {    
  // Called when value of message changes
}, [message]);
```

Comment: Ok, i understood this. But what i exactly asking is consider i have 2 functions, function A and function B. Function A should only be called at once while mounting the component and at that time function B should not be called and function B should only called while component updates at that time function A should not call. How can we achieve this using useEffect hook ?

Answer (score 1):

I saw the comment you had for @Surjeet Bhadauriya, there is no specific hook that handle this scenario, but you could easily have a work around this.

Here is an example

```js
const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  // your code on didMount;
  setDidMount(true);

}, []);


useEffect(() => {
  if (!didMount)
    return;
  // your code on didUpdate;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alen.Toma, I also end up with this. I just want to make sure that there is no built in functionality to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Typography } from '@mui/material';
const First = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(0);
    const [componentDidMount, setComponentDidMount] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("This is the mounting phase")
        setComponentDidMount(true);
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!componentDidMount) {
            return;
        }
        console.log("This will work after component re render it self due to some state change")
    },[state])
    return (
        <>
            <Typography variant="h1">Start</Typography>
            <Button onClick={() => {
                setState(state + 1);
            }} color="secondary" variant="contained">Click {state}</Button>
            {
                console.log("Component Renders")
            }
        </>
    );
};
export default First;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).