# How to convert from recompose to hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, recompose

My company is using recompose as our state management tool. We are refactoring our application to use hooks. For the code below, how would you replace recompose component with react hook components?

I understand that withState becomes useState, such as:

```
withState('something', 'setSomething', null)
```

becomes

```
const [something, setSomething] = useState(null);
```

What would `withProps`, `withHandlers`, `compose`, `hoistStatics` and `lifecycle` change to?

How would `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` work?

```
import { compose, hoistStatics, withHandlers, withState, withProps, lifecycle } from 'recompose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import myComponent from './myComponent'

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {

  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({

  }, dispatch)
};

const enhancer = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps),
  withProps(props => ({
    myProp: props.myProp,
  })),
  withState('something', 'setSomething', null),
  withState('somethingElse', 'setSomethingElse', null),
  withHandlers({
    myFunction: () => () => {
      console.log(`I need help`);
    }
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {

    },
    componentDidUpdate() {

    }
  })
);

export default hoistStatics(enhancer)(myComponent);
```

Answer (score 8):

Citing Dan Abramov:

> To get productive, you need to “think in effects”, and their mental
>   model is closer to implementing synchronization than to responding to
>   lifecycle events.

We can not replace hooks and hocs 1:1, since they are different programming models.
Still, we can try migrating by:

`withProps` - can be replaced as const inside the component

`withHandlers` - can be replaced as an arrow function inside the component

`lifecycle` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55502524/3439101

A simple example (not with all the cases):

with **hocs**

```
const enhancer = compose(
  withProps(props => ({
    myProp: props.myProp,
  })),
  withState('something', 'setSomething', null),
  withHandlers({
    myFunction: () => () => {
      console.log(`I need help`);
    }
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('mounted')
    }
  })
);
```

with **hooks**

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  const [something, setSomthing] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mounted')
  }, [])

  const myProp = props.myProp

  const myFunction = () => {
    console.log(`I need help`);
  }
}
```

Comment: const myProp = props.myProp -> if the prop is related to other props calculate and those props need to be updated to lastest ? because it's const it shouldn't be updated am i wrong.???

Answer (score 3):

You are right, `withState` can be replaced with `useState`.

For Redux part, React recommend to keep using the API in the same way you have been using it, but you should take this out from `compose`. In `react-redux` v7 a new hook will be implemented for this.

Now `withHandlers`, can be replaced with plain javascript functions, add it to your component or any other file

Before:

```
withHandlers({
    myFunc() => () => {console.log('hello')}
})
```

Now:

```
const myFunc = () => {console.log('hello')}
```

Last but not least, `componentDidMount` and `componendDidUpdate` will need to be replaced with [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Here there will be a little bit of reading to understand how this works but it is not hard. You will create effects that are basically functions that run every single render, you can pass a second parameter if you want this to run only when something has changed, similar to `componentDidUpdate` or an empty array if you want to run only once similar to `componentDidMount`. Do not think of effects as replacement of lifecycle events, but you can achieve the same results. Have a look of [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) I found it quite useful.

There are few other hooks available, I found `useContext`, `useCallback` and `useReducer` very nice to use .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer and the articles are very useful. Do you have any idea what could substitute for `withProps` and `hoistStatics`?