# Is it possible to export react component as function in non-react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to export react component as function and pass in props as params of the function in non-react project?

I am recently finished a react project with create-react-app. Now i wanted to use it to other non-react project(pure Javascript + html, Angular etc).

However, since these projects can not just use the component in React fashion(composition). I am wondering if we can export react component as function, so we can just use it across different projects without worrying about react's architect.

For instance:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {"Hello World" + this.prop.name}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And then export it as function. So in the non-react project, i can do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Non-React App</title>
  </head>
    <script src="https://mydisk/ImportMyReact.js" ></script>

    <script>
      MyComponent("Jake")  
    </script>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use webpack to bundle it, but I have no luck because the bundle.js is a giant piece of code that I cant just import certain function out of it.

Comment: You make a build as a UMD Module.

Comment: @epascarello that's what I have tried with Webpack. Did not have luck with it. I do not wish to publish it to npm because my other project does not use node(ASP.MVC). Is there other options without publishing it to npm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React functional stateless component, PureComponent, Component; what are the differences and when should we use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703675/react-functional-stateless-component-purecomponent-component-what-are-the-dif)

Comment: @JaredSmith I did look into functional component and such. It is not helpful because my component in reality needs to be a class because I am using life-cycle methods.

Comment: I believe you may need WebComponent as adapter layer. take a look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-web-component

Comment: @aDev [not anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214725/3757232).

Comment: So you want to use React without using React? No, that's not possible. React is the thing that makes React components work.

Comment: @JLRishe No, what I am trying to say is that I am trying to use React in a non-react project in a sense that other people who uses my react code does not have to know React to use it. It is like a SDK if that makes sense where the actual React is encapsulated so the people who uses my code do not have to know React to use it.

Comment: Check servicebot opensource project. @ZpfSysn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create a function that will render a react component in a nonreact project, you can do that, but it's going to need to make use of reactDom.render, since that's the only way to take a react component and render it to the dom.

React components do not modify the dom themselves. All they do is create the "virtual dom", which is a set of types and props that react-dom can then use to update the dom. For example, let's take the very simplest of components:

```
() => <div/>
```

After transpiling the jsx, this turns into:

```
() => React.createElement("div", null);
```

And if you were to run this function, the result is a plain javascript object that looks like this:

```
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
  key: null,
  props: {},
  ref: null,
  type: 'div'
}
```

More complicated components will create more complicated objects, and in the case of class components they create it via their render method, but in all cases the result is just a plain object. The dom has not been updated in creating this object, and the component contains no logic for updating the dom. It's React-Dom's job to take that object and figure out how to update the dom.

---

Here's an example of how you might package up a function for use in a non-react application which renders a react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // etc
}

export default function renderMyComponent(element, name) {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent name={name}>, element);
}


/** somewhere else: **/

renderMyComponent(document.getElementById('main'), 'Jake');
```

Comment: I am sorry if I am not clear. I am not asking for help to pass data as props and render them. rather, I am trying to  find it way to "export it as function" so i can use it in non-react environment. Also, since I am trying to use it in non-react project, i think ReactDom.render() would not be idea since it is still React

Comment: `rather, I am trying to find it way to "export it as function" so i can use it in non-react environment` yes, that's exactly what i was trying to demonstrate. renderMyComponent is a function that can be used in any project, react or otherwise. That function will then render a MyComponent .`Also, since I am trying to use it in non-react project, i think ReactDom.render() would not be idea since it is still React` ReactDom.render is the only way to render a react component to the dom.

Comment: Is there a way to just 'export default' the component and calling ReactDOM.render() on the non-react (plain javascript)? Like:


`<script  type="module" type="text/javascript">

  import ReactMap from '/react_build/ReactMap.bundle.js';

  var domContainer = document.querySelector('#mapbox_div');

  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(ReactMap), domContainer);

<script/>`

Answer (score -1):

You can import another component and call it like this:

```
import SecondComponent from './SecondComponent'

export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
<SecondComponent />
) }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if I am not clear. I am not asking for help to pass data as props. rather, I am trying to  find it way to "export it as function" so i can use it in non-react environment

Comment: Sure you can do that, react is all about components hence you can define your components and can easily call inside in your class.

Comment: I am trying to do it in a "non-react-environment".

Comment: He is looking for transfer react component to non react project @RitvizSharma