# What happened with the render() after React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Before Hooks, with class based we used a lot `render()` and it did exactly what is says, compares the previous DOM with the current one, if they're different, React is going to re-render the component.

But now, with React Hooks, usually we only use `return()` to return things and also render, I'm right?

Is `return()` doing the same as `render()` did before Hooks? If not, which is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return()` and `render()` are simply the same. If you write a component as function, you use `return()`.

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

If you write a component as class, you use `render()`.

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

However, in the past, you do you not have state/lifecycle method in a functional component. To solve that, React introduced Hooks. In the past you have to define state in constructor, now you define it in a function like this:

```
function ExampleWithManyStates() {
  const [age, setAge] = useState(42);
  const [fruit, setFruit] = useState('banana');
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([{ text: 'Learn Hooks' }]);
}
```

Also, you can have life cycle methods with hooks as mentioned in this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214465/how-to-use-lifecycle-methods-with-hooks-in-react) post